# Semantic UI Modal Closes As Soon As It Opens

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, semantic-ui

I am new-ish to Semantic UI, but have really liked what I've seen so far. I'm working on a site/app that lets users review documents using the Spring MVC framework and Thymeleaf.

The reviewer clicks a button and it brings up a PDF of their review document. They can leave comments which are entered into a database and displayed as a table for the writer to evaluate when all the reviews are complete. I also want to add the ability for a reviewer to edit comments.

I have two modals. One that is called when the reviewer wants to add a new comment and and one that is called when the reviewer wants to edit the comment. They are styled identically, but the main difference is that the edit modal preloads the text input with the comment.

The modal to add the comment works perfectly. The modal to update the comment does not. It opens, loads the content of the comment in the text box, and then closes immediately.

Below is the code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addComment").click(function(){
        $('#addCommentModal').modal('show');
    });

    $(".modifyCommentButton").click(function(){
        $('#modifyCommentModal').modal('show');
        $('#commentInput').val($(this).parent().parent().siblings('.commentContent').text());
     });
 });
```

Modals:

```
<div id="modifyCommentModal" class="ui basic modal">
    <div class="ui icon header">
        <i class="blue plus circle icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div  class="content">
            <form  th:action="@{'/addcomment/'+${review.getTaskId()}}" th:object="${newComment}" method="post" class="ui form">
                <input id="commentInput" class="field" type="text" th:field="*{comment}" />
                <button id="modifyButtonAdd" class="ui green animated inverted fade button" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="visible content">Add</div>
                    <div class="hidden content">
                        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button id="modifyButtonCancel" class="ui red animated inverted fade button cancel" tabindex="0" type="reset">
                    <div class="visible content">Cancel</div>
                    <div class="hidden content">
                        <i class="remove icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="addCommentModal" class="ui basic modal">
    <div class="ui icon header">
        <i class="blue plus circle icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div  class="content">
            <form  th:action="@{'/addcomment/'+${review.getTaskId()}}" th:object="${newComment}" method="post" class="ui form">
                <input id="" class="field" type="text" th:field="*{comment}" />
                <button id="formButtonAdd" class="ui green animated inverted fade button" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="visible content">Add</div>
                    <div class="hidden content">
                        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button id="formButtonCancel" class="ui red animated inverted fade button cancel" tabindex="0" type="reset">
                    <div class="visible content">Cancel</div>
                    <div class="hidden content">
                        <i class="remove icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I realize that I need a different th:action in the review modal to write the comment to the same field it was in... but I was going to figure that out when I got the modal to stay open. :)

Any insight would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Safari?

Comment: No. Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Did you try to set the comment text before you open the modal?